# Finding Users first tournament based on action date

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that includes each registration a user has completed for tournaments.
This table can have a user register for many tournaments over time.

It consists of user_id, tournament_id, and created_at date field

I need to see each users first tournament.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT user_id, MIN(created_at) AS first_participation_date, tournament_id
FROM participant_status
GROUP BY user_id, tournament_id
ORDER BY user_id, first_participation_date ASC;
```

But grouping on both ids will give me duplicates obvservations of users.

Answer (score 0):

A `FIRST_VALUE` window function with a `DISTINCT` to remove the duplicates will do what you want.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       user_id,
       FIRST_VALUE(created_at)    OVER w AS first_participation_date,
       FIRST_VALUE(tournament_id) OVER w AS first_tournament_id
FROM participant_status
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at)
```

Alternatively, you can work with the `ROW_NUMBER()`, `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()` window functions.
The query is a little bit more complex but much more flexible: it allows you to select the firsts `N` tournaments instead of only the very first one and the different window functions handle ties (= several registrations on the same day) differently from one another.
Here is the version with `ROW_NUMBER()`.

```
SELECT user_id, created_at, tournament_id
FROM (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at) AS NumParticipation
    FROM participant_status
) T
WHERE NumParticipation <= 1
```